# child-component instance using <child-comp> vs <component :is="child-component">

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

i would like to know please the difference between instantiating an instance of a child-component as follows:

```
<template>
<img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
<HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
</template>
```

and as shown in the following fashion:

```
<template>
<img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
<component :is="HelloWorld" msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
</template>
```

for the former approach, at run time, i do not receive any warning messages.however, for the latter one, i receive the following warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Property "HelloWorld" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance
```

please let me know why i am receiving this warning when the second approach is applied..and what is the difference between the two of them please

**helloWorld.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    {{msg}}
  </div>
</template>
```